# How to derivate the DFT of the time-domain samples?

Tags: dft

I am currently reading a paper titled 'Channel Estimation and Data Detection for Insufficient Cyclic Prefix MIMO-OFDM' published in IEEE Transactions on Vehicular Technology. As you can see below, the authors mentioned transforming the time-domain samples (2) into frequency-domain samples (3) using the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT). However, no matter how I manipulate the equations, I cannot derive the frequency-domain sample expressions.

[image]

[image]

I am keen to understand the process of converting the time-domain samples to frequency-domain samples as described in this paper. Unfortunately, I have been unable to reach the author for clarification. Specifically, I am puzzled about how the summation for frequency-domain offset could be incorporated into the formula for frequency-domain samples in (3). Is it possible that obtaining a sample for a single frequency offset includes a summation of other frequency-domain samples within that single sample?

Comment: welcome to SP Stackexchange! There are a LOT of symbols in this equation. It would  help if you define them all properly  or at least add a link to a publicly available copy of this article.